# Почему не отображается последним действием результат примера?

Tags: javascript

```
<meta charset="utf-8"> 
<script> 
    var a = parseInt(prompt("Введите первое число:")); 
    var b = parseInt(prompt("Введите второе второе число:")); 
    alert(a+b); 
    var c = parseInt(prompt("Отними:")) 
    alert("Результат="+(a+b)-с); 
</script>
```

Ребят,почему у меня нет строчки с ответом?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Потому что 'c' в строке "var c" и 'с' в строке "(a+b)-с);" разные.
У одного 'c' код 99 -- ENG
У другого 'с' код 1089 -- РУС

---

Чтобы получить ответ надо добавить круглые скобки `((a + b) - c)`.

```
<script>
  var a = parseInt(prompt("Введите первое число:"));
  var b = parseInt(prompt("Введите второе второе число:"));
  alert(a + b);
  var c = parseInt(prompt("Отними:"))
  alert("Результат=" + ((a + b) - c));
</script>
```

Comment: исправила,но теперь вместо ответа с цифрами появилась строка NaN

Comment: @polin _"вместо ответа с цифрами появилась строка NaN"_ -- скобки надо добавить. добавил в ответ

Comment: после добавления скобки вообще перестало всё работать

Comment: @polin _"после добавления скобки вообще перестало всё работать"_ -- надо две скобки. перед `а` и  после `c`. попробуйте просто скопировать код из моего ответа и запустите.

Answer (score 2):

Нет ; в конце var c = parseInt(prompt("Отними:"))